# ImageMagick: Looking for a fast way to blur an image

Tags: perl, image-processing, imagemagick, gaussian, gaussianblur

I am searching for a **faster way to blur** an image than to use the **GaussianBlur**.
The **solution** I am looking for **can be a command line solution**, but I prefer code in perl notation.

Actually, we use the Perl image magick API to blur images:

```
# $image is our Perl object holding a imagemagick perl image
# level is a natural number between 1 and 10
$image->GaussianBlur('x' . $level);
```

This works fine, but with the level height the amount of time it consumes seems to grow exponentially.

**Question:** How can I improve the time used for the bluring operation?
Is there another faster approach to blur images?

Comment: Does the type of blur matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation speaks of the difference between *Blur* and *GaussianBlur*](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#blur_gaussian).

> There has been some confusion as to which operator, "-blur" or the
>   "-gaussian-blur" is better for blurring images. First of all "-blur"
>   is faster, but it does this using two stage technique. First in one
>   axis, then in the other. The "-gaussian-blur" operator on the other
>   hand is more mathematically correct as it blurs in all directions
>   simultaneously. The speed cost between the two can be enormous, by a
>   factor of 10 or more, depending on the amount of bluring involved.
>
> [...]
>
> In summary, the two operators are slightly different, but only
>   minimally. As "-blur" is much faster, use it. I do in just about all
>   the examples involving blurring. Large

That would simply be:

```
$image->Blur( 'x' . $level );
```

But the [Perl ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/perl-magick.html#manipulate) has the same text on both `Blur` and `GaussianBlur` (emphasis mine). I can't try now, you would have to benchmark it yourself.

> *Blur:* reduce image noise and reduce detail levels with a Gaussian operator of the given radius and standard deviation (sigma).
>
> *GaussianBlur:* reduce image noise and reduce detail levels with a Gaussian operator of the given radius and standard deviation (sigma).

An [alternative that the documentation also lists](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#blur_resize) is resizing the image to be very tiny, and then enlarging again.

> Using large sigma values for image bluring is very slow. But onw
>   technique can be used to speed up this process. This however is only a
>   rough method and could use some mathematicaly rigor to improve
>   results. Essentually the reason large blurs are slow is because you
>   need a large window or 'kernel' to merge lots of pixels together, for
>   each and every pixel in the image. However resize (making image
>   smaller) does the same thing but generates fewer pixels in the
>   process. The technique is basically shrink the image, then enlarge it
>   again to generate the heavilly blured result. The Gaussian Filter is
>   especially useful for this as you can directly specify a Gaussian
>   Sigma define.

The example command line code is this:

> ```
> convert  rose: -blur 0x5   rose_blur_5.png
> convert rose: -filter Gaussian -resize 50% \
>       -define filter:sigma=2.5 -resize 200%  rose_resize_5.png
> ```

Comment: thx, that was exactly, what i was looking for. I had googled a bit, but had not found it myself.

Answer (score 18):

I found that [the suggested method](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#blur_resize) of resizing image for blur imitation makes output look very pixelated for very large values of sigma like 25 or more. So I finally came to an idea of downscale-blur-enlarge, which makes very nice result (almost indistinguishable from simple blur with large sigma):

```
# plain slow blur
convert -blur 0x25 sample.jpg blurred_slow.jpg
# much faster
convert -scale 10% -blur 0x2.5 -resize 1000% sample.jpg blurred_fast.jpg
```

On my i5 2.7Ghz it shows up to 10x speed up.

Comment: I have a 4k screen, and this still took 1s with an i7 (laptop, don't remember speed atm).  but scaling down to 5%, and going up 20k% took 0.2s

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if I could still help OP with this, but I recently tried the same for a blurred screenlock picture.
I found that **omitting the -blur** part saves even more calculation time and is still delivering great results for a 4K picture:

```
convert in.png -scale 2.5% -resize 4000% out.png
# real: 0.174s user: 0.144s size: 1.2MiB

convert in.png -scale 10% -blur 0x2.5 -resize 1000% out.png
# real: 0.136s user: 2.117s size: 1.2MiB

convert in.png -blur 0x25 out.png
# real: 2.425s user: 21.408s size: 1KiB
```

However, you couldn't go lower than 2.5% with 3840x2160. It will resize the image. I guess the eps value differs for pictures of other sizes.

It should be noted, that the resulting image sizes differ noticably!